# React Native, Using Async Storage to Set and Get same Value in Render

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, dom

I want to Set a Value and Get it in Render with one line code, by adding a Variable between  tags. This could shows error :(Can't find variable: storage_key)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

class SyncRu extends Component {
    state = {
       'storage_Key': ''
   }
   render() {
       const storeData = async (value) => {
          try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
        } catch (e) {
            // saving error
        }
    }
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
            if (value !== null) {
                // value previously stored
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
        }
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {storage_Key}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
export default SyncRu
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized the state incorrectly. Instead of:

```
state = {
   'storage_Key': ''
}
```

You have to use:

```
this.state = {storage_Key: ""};
```

After you access your data from AsyncStorage you have to use setState, for updating your UI.

```
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
if (value !== null) {
   this.setState({
      storage_Key: value
   });
}
```

Also have a look at the documentation of React State.
[React State Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @HowardJohn I've edit my post above. Did it work? Don't forget to close the issue by accepting as an answer if it works :)